# Yesod tutorial compile error: Not in scope: ‘runResourceT’

Tags: haskell, yesod

experts

I'm following the Yesod tutorial on fpcomplete (part 3) https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/building-a-file-hosting-service-in-yesod/part%203, but got stuck.

When I compile the project, got this error: Handler/Home.hs:29:26: Not in scope: ‘runResourceT’

I'm using GHC 7.8 and the Stackage build: http://www.stackage.org/stackage/cd04dd6aad3aa5f097598adc050e4f02e571adbc

Did something changed about runResourceT in 7.8? I'm a newbie to Haskell, and not familar with the libraries.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that an older version of `Data.Conduit` might have exported `ResourceT` directly, but nowadays you need to import it explicitly with

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
```